# acumatica import items with image API

Tags: c#, image, api, import, acumatica

Now I have successfully working code (with multiple threads) for items bulk import in IN202500 screen in Acumatica.

The problem is that I am struggling to import an image of an item and actually I don't have an image by itself but only URL link to this image.

So, my question is has anyone done this in c#?

This is my piece of code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ItemImportMultiThreaded
{
    public class ItemImporter
    {
        private IN202500.Screen _itemsScreen;
        private static object _itemsSchemaLock = new object();
        private static IN202500.Content _itemsSchema;

        public void Login(string url, string username, string password, string company)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Logging in to {1}...", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, url);

            _itemsScreen = new IN202500.Screen();
            _itemsScreen.Url = url + "/PMSDB/(W(2))/Soap/IN202500.asmx";
            _itemsScreen.EnableDecompression = true;
            _itemsScreen.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
            _itemsScreen.Timeout = 36000;
            _itemsScreen.Login(username, password);



            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Logged in to {1}.", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, url);

            lock (_itemsSchemaLock)
            {
                // Threads can share the same schema.
                if (_itemsSchema == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Retrieving IN202500 schema...", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    _itemsSchema = _itemsScreen.GetSchema();
                    if (_itemsSchema == null) throw new Exception("IN202500 GetSchema returned null. See AC-73433.");
                }
            }
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            _itemsScreen.Logout();
        }

        public void Import(List<Item> items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Submitting {1} items to Acumatica...", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, items.Count);

            var commands = new IN202500.Command[]
            {
                _itemsSchema.StockItemSummary.InventoryID,
                _itemsSchema.StockItemSummary.Description,
                _itemsSchema.GeneralSettingsItemDefaults.ItemClass,
                _itemsSchema.VendorDetails.VendorID,
                _itemsSchema.VendorDetails.VendorInventoryID,
                _itemsSchema.VendorDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                _itemsSchema.VendorDetails.VendorID,
                _itemsSchema.VendorDetails.VendorInventoryID,
                _itemsSchema.VendorDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
                _itemsSchema.VendorDetails.VendorID,
                _itemsSchema.VendorDetails.VendorInventoryID,
                _itemsSchema.CrossReference.AlternateID,
                _itemsSchema.CrossReference.Description,

                _itemsSchema.Actions.Save
            };

            string[][] data = new string[items.Count][];

            int count = 0;
            foreach(Item item in items)
            {
                data[count] = new string[11];
                data[count][0] = item.InventoryID;
                data[count][1] = item.Description.Trim();
                data[count][2] = item.ItemClassID;
                data[count][3] = item.DigiKey;
                data[count][4] = item.DKPN;
                data[count][5] = item.Mouser;
                data[count][6] = item.MouserID;
                data[count][7] = item.Element14;
                data[count][8] = item.Element14ID;
                data[count][9] = item.AlternateID;
                data[count][10] = item.Descr;
                count++;
            }

            _itemsScreen.Import(commands, null, data, false, true, true);

            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Submitted {1} items to Acumatica.", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, items.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use `FileStream` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If by URL link you mean an external http resource, you can download the image and upload it.

The StockItems image field cycle through all the images contained in the Files popup in the order they are displayed:
[image: Files Popup]

I uploaded the images from a static external Url using the following code:

```
    const string imageUrl = "https://cdn.acumatica.com/media/2016/03/software-technology-industries-small.jpg";
    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), ".jpg"));

    // Download Image
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(new Uri(imageUrl), path);
    }

    // ReadUploadFile function below
    byte[] data = ReadUploadFile(path);

    _itemsScreen.Import(new IN202500.Command[]
    {
        // Get Inventory Item
        new Value
        {
            Value = "D1",
            LinkedCommand = _itemsSchema.StockItemSummary.InventoryID,
        },
        _itemsSchema.Actions.Save,
        // Upload Inventory Item Image
        new Value
        {
            FieldName = Path.GetFileName(path),
            LinkedCommand = _itemsSchema.StockItemSummary.ServiceCommands.Attachment
        },
        _itemsSchema.Actions.Save
    },
    null,
    new string[][]
    {
        new string[]
        {
            // Image data
            Convert.ToBase64String(data)
        }
    },
    false,
    false,
    true);

public byte[] ReadUploadFile(string filePath)
{
    byte[] filedata;

    using (FileStream file = File.Open(filePath,
                                        FileMode.Open,
                                        FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                                        FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        filedata = new byte[file.Length];
        file.Read(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);
    }

    if (filedata == null || filedata.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Concat("Invalid or empty file: ", filePath));
    }

    return filedata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below, Tested Code.

```
var content = _context.CR306000GetSchema(); _context.CR306000Clear();

var commands = new List();

ReqParameter(content, ref commands);

commands.Add(content.Actions.Save);

commands.Add(content.CaseSummary.CaseID);

var orderResults = _context.CR306000Submit(commands.ToArray());

private static void ReqParameter(CR306000Content content, ref List cmds) { if (cmds == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("cmds");


 private static void ReqParameter(CR306000Content content, ref List<Command> cmds)
        {
            if (cmds == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("cmds");        

            byte[] filedata= null;            
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://cdn.acumatica.com/media/2016/03/software-technology-industries-small.jpg");  // change the required url of the data that has to be fetched 

            if (uri.IsFile)
            {
                string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
                filedata = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uri.LocalPath);
            }
            if (filedata == null)
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                filedata = wc.DownloadData(uri);
            }

            cmds = new List<Command>
            {

                //Case Header Details
                new Value { Value="<NEW>",LinkedCommand = content.CaseSummary.CaseID},
                new Value { Value="L41",LinkedCommand = content.CaseSummary.ClassID},
                new Value { Value="ABCSTUDIOS",LinkedCommand = content.CaseSummary.BusinessAccount, Commit = true},          
                new Value { Value="Test subject created from envelop call 11C",LinkedCommand = content.CaseSummary.Subject},           

                // body of the case 
                new Value{Value= "Body of the content for created through envelop call 11B", LinkedCommand = content.Details.Description},


                //Attaching a file
                new Value
                {
                    Value = Convert.ToBase64String(filedata),   // byte data that is passed to through envelop 
                    FieldName = "Test.jpg",
                    LinkedCommand =
                content.CaseSummary.ServiceCommands.Attachment
                },


             };
        }
```

Let me know if this works for you.
Thanks